# nvcc fatal: Visual Studio configuration file 'vsvars32.bat' could not be found (VS 2017)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

I am trying to build a cuda/c++ program in Visual Studio 2017. It might be worth noting that my computer also has VS 2013 installed. I have tried placing vsvars32.bat in the same directory as it is for VS 2013 but the error did not change. I don't know where it's supposed to go because of the `x64/../../..`

```
>------ Build started: Project: CMakeLists, Configuration: Debug ------
  [1/5] cmd.exe /C "cd /D "D:\Users\adm_lab\CMakeBuilds\3f75e69e-932c-9435-a942-a027b1514a1d\build\x64-Debug (default)\CMakeFiles\voxelizer.dir" && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E make_directory "D:/Users/adm_lab/CMakeBuilds/3f75e69e-932c-9435-a942-a027b1514a1d/build/x64-Debug (default)/CMakeFiles/voxelizer.dir//." && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -D verbose:BOOL=OFF -D build_configuration:STRING=Debug -D "generated_file:STRING=D:/Users/adm_lab/CMakeBuilds/3f75e69e-932c-9435-a942-a027b1514a1d/build/x64-Debug (default)/CMakeFiles/voxelizer.dir//./voxelizer_generated_main.cu.obj" -D "generated_cubin_file:STRING=D:/Users/adm_lab/CMakeBuilds/3f75e69e-932c-9435-a942-a027b1514a1d/build/x64-Debug (default)/CMakeFiles/voxelizer.dir//./voxelizer_generated_main.cu.obj.cubin.txt" -P "D:/Users/adm_lab/CMakeBuilds/3f75e69e-932c-9435-a942-a027b1514a1d/build/x64-Debug (default)/CMakeFiles/voxelizer.dir//voxelizer_generated_main.cu.obj.Debug.cmake""
  FAILED: CMakeFiles/voxelizer.dir/voxelizer_generated_main.cu.obj 
  cmd.exe /C "cd /D "D:\Users\adm_lab\CMakeBuilds\3f75e69e-932c-9435-a942-a027b1514a1d\build\x64-Debug (default)\CMakeFiles\voxelizer.dir" && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E make_directory "D:/Users/adm_lab/CMakeBuilds/3f75e69e-932c-9435-a942-a027b1514a1d/build/x64-Debug (default)/CMakeFiles/voxelizer.dir//." && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -D verbose:BOOL=OFF -D build_configuration:STRING=Debug -D "generated_file:STRING=D:/Users/adm_lab/CMakeBuilds/3f75e69e-932c-9435-a942-a027b1514a1d/build/x64-Debug (default)/CMakeFiles/voxelizer.dir//./voxelizer_generated_main.cu.obj" -D "generated_cubin_file:STRING=D:/Users/adm_lab/CMakeBuilds/3f75e69e-932c-9435-a942-a027b1514a1d/build/x64-Debug (default)/CMakeFiles/voxelizer.dir//./voxelizer_generated_main.cu.obj.cubin.txt" -P "D:/Users/adm_lab/CMakeBuilds/3f75e69e-932c-9435-a942-a027b1514a1d/build/x64-Debug (default)/CMakeFiles/voxelizer.dir//voxelizer_generated_main.cu.obj.Debug.cmake""
  nvcc fatal   : Visual Studio configuration file 'vsvars32.bat' could not be found for installation at 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/HostX64/x64/../../..'
  CMake Error at voxelizer_generated_main.cu.obj.Debug.cmake:219 (message):
    Error generating
    D:/Users/adm_lab/CMakeBuilds/3f75e69e-932c-9435-a942-a027b1514a1d/build/x64-Debug
    (default)/CMakeFiles/voxelizer.dir//./voxelizer_generated_main.cu.obj


  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Build failed.
```

edit: thought I should add that the computer this is on does not have an internet connection so I used the local cache method outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) to install VS.

Answer (score 1):

Please, double-check your Visual Studio 2017 instance is up to date. Then repair your Visual Studio instance via the Visual Studio Installer:

1. Start **Visual Studio Installer**.
2. Click the **Details** icon icon in front of your Visual Studio 2017 installation, and then click **Repair**.

Read [Microsoft Docs | Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio) for more information.

Comment: Will this help if the computer does not have an internet connection?

Comment: @alex.l I am not sure whether you can repair Visual Studio 2017 when offline. It was possible with older versions.

Comment: I did an offline repair but still have the exact same problem.